# How to restore CSS style to its super class

Tags: css

If I've overridden a CSS root style to:

```
body .dijitTitlePane .dijitTitlePaneTextNode {
    color: #FFFFFF;
    font-family: Verdana, arial;
    font-size: small;
    font-weight: bold;
}
```

now I want to use the original `.dijitTitlePane .dijitTitlePaneTextNode` CSS style, is there a "super" class definition I can use here?
Thanks,

David

Comment: can you not just remove your override?

Comment: Where does the overridden style come from? If it has a less specific selector, then you can in principle get at it; but if you have changed properties for the same selector, I believe that you have not over*rid*den but over*writ*ten the former values and they are no longer available.

Comment: what do you mean by 'CSS root style'? Please provide an example of your original style and the over-ride.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try:

```
html body .dijitTitlePane .dijitTitlePaneTextNode {
    color: #FFFFFF;
    font-family: Verdana, arial;
    font-size: small;
    font-weight: bold;
}
```

Another alternative, if you don't care about IE6 support: you can put !important on whatever style you want to override everything else.

```
.dijitTitlePane .dijitTitlePaneTextNode {
     font-size: small !important;
}
```

Comment: A note about inheritance: the inherit value doesn't work for all CSS properties in all values.

Comment: -1 is for `!important` - I think it's a terrible idea to use `!important` in general.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `inherit for the style you need:

```
body .dijitTitlePane .dijitTitlePaneTextNode {
     color: #FFFFFF;
     font-family: Verdana, arial;
     font-size: small;
     font-weight: inherit;
}
```

Here, `font-weight` will use the "super" style.

EDIT: After the style is defined there is no way to get at the "super" value. However, you can override the overriden value *again* in the page element:

```
<body class="dijitTitlePane" style="font-weight: normal">
```

CSS doesn't provide a reverting mechanism. The only way for a root style to cascade to a child style is for the child to leave it undefined or defined as `inherit`.

Comment: He said he wanted the original ".dijitTitlePane .dijitTitlePaneTextNode" style: if that wasn't a typing error, then he doesn't mean the inherited value, he means whatever there would have been if he hadn't had that rule.

Comment: yeah, we use dojo, and one of its css sets, namely, tundra.css. We customized some of the styles for widgets to create custom look, now I just want to use the default style specified in tundra.css. Maybe I should just copy and paste whatever definition in tundra.css, but just thought there should be a better way of doing this.

Answer (score -1):

You may need to clarify why you are re-assigning styles to the same classes.

You don't typically want to rewrite style declarations for the same class names. Instead add/remove additional classes to the objects you want to over-ride.

So, your default:

```
<div class="standardStyle"></div>
```

To over-ride, you can do something like this:

```
<div class="standardStyle additionalOverrideStyle"></div>
```

Then, when done, remove it.

Comment: this is from an older part of codes that styles of certain dojo widgets were overridden to provide a customized look. Now I'm trying to use the default widget style for one widget, but just couldn't find a good way of doing it.

Comment: alas, there probably is no 'good' way of doing it. I'd probably copy the original styles and give them new class name ala "classicStyle".

Answer (score -1):

No!

The use of the terms "super class" and "inerhitance" and "overriding" in this question demonstrates' most developers misconception of CSS, as they try to think of it as a programming language or even an Object Oriented Programming Language, with the so-called ["CSS Class"](http://richard.jp.leguen.ca/not-blog/a-css-class) doubling as an OOP Class.

This is a fundamental misunderstanding of what CSS is for, which causes developers to try and make their CSS too general for its own good.

It's important to remember that graphic designers would be the primary stakeholder in mind for the creators of CSS, not developers. Graphic designers have no notion of the the founding principles of object oriented programming - polymorphism, inheritance and encapsulation - which are intuitive for developers. Even the use of variables is a programmer-specific thing - hence why CSS doesn't have variables!

So, instead of thinking about it all in terms of inheritance, learn about [specificity](http://www.w3.org/TR/css3-selectors/#specificity).

Comment: There are valid reasons for considering a general system of class names. Things like the (admittedly poorly named) OOCSS model has uses in large dev teams. But, yes, indeed...CSS is not anything like a OO language. (though things like LessCSS are attempting to bring that model into the workflow)